# Finding sum of real roots when when higher roots given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the sum of real roots of the equation

$(2+(2+(2+x)^2)^2)^2=2000$

i tried taking square root of both sides but couldn't come up with something.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

(Turkish Math Olympiads 2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the square root of both sides then we get:$$(2+(2+x)^2)^2=-2\pm\sqrt{2000}$$We then take the square root of both sides again but, since it is asking for just the **real** roots we can ignore $-2-\sqrt{2000}$. So we get:$$(2+x)^2=-2\pm\sqrt{-2+\sqrt{2000}}$$Repeating this process we get:$$x=-2\pm\sqrt{-2+\sqrt{-2+\sqrt{2000}}}$$From here I hope you can see what the sum of the **real** roots would be?

Answer (score 2):

we can find out that 
$(2+x)^2>0$

if $(2+x)^2=t$

In this case 
$|x+2|=\sqrt{t}$

$x_1=\sqrt{t}=x+2$
 $x_1=\sqrt{t}-2$

and

$x_2=-\sqrt{t}=x+2$
  $x_2=-\sqrt{t}-2$

$x_1+x_2=\sqrt{t}-\sqrt{t}-2-2=-4$

(EDIT: NOT MY SOLUTION)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $$- \left( {x}^{4}+8\,{x}^{3}+28\,{x}^{2}+20\,\sqrt {5}+48\,x+38
 \right)  \left( -{x}^{4}-8\,{x}^{3}-28\,{x}^{2}+20\,\sqrt {5}-48\,x-
38 \right) 
=0$$